# Concat two maps in golang

Tags: go

I know about the `append` function in golang, but is there a similar function to append two maps.

```
slice1 := []string{"hello"}
slice2 := []string{"world"}

combined := append(slice1, slice2...)
```

I tried to do the same thing with maps, but it gave me this error:

> first argument to append must be slice; have map[string]string

Is therea a method to append two maps in go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a loop or two.

```
map1 := map[string]int{
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
}
map2 := map[string]int{
    "uno": 1,
    "dos": 2,
}

combined := map[string]int{}
for k, v := range map1 {
    combined[k] = v
}
for k, v := range map2 {
    combined[k] = v
}

fmt.Println(combined) // map[dos:2 one:1 two:2 uno:1]
```

[Try it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KDT5kX3W9H4).

Order matters, of course, if the two maps have overlapping sets of keys.

Comment: I guess I could just use 1 loop if I wanted to keep map1 and append map2 into it right? `for k, v := range map2 { map1[k] = v }`

Comment: @Blaisem yes, as long as you don't need the original (un-merged) contents of map1.

Comment: Ah just saw the playground link. Makes sense thank you.